# inherit width doesn't work with percentage value

Tags: css

I have 2 `div`s. The parent `div` has `relative` position and the child `div` has `fixed` position.

If I use a flat amount of `width` on the parent `div`, `width: inherit;` works perfectly.
When I use `width: 100%;` on the parent `div`, child `div` has more `width` than its parent.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixedElement {
  position: fixed;
  width: inherit;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  parent
  <div class="fixedElement">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/537yzrpy/14/)

Am I missing something here?

I'm thinking of using `jQuery` to set the `width` of the child but I'm sure it's not a good solution as it could be solved only with `css`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `body` has a default `margin`. So the parent element will fill the entire width but will be limited due to that margin. The fixed element is not bound to the `body` and is the full width regardless of the margin.

However, it sticks out to the right of the parent because it is in the parent which has a `position: relative`. If you add a CSS rule like

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

parent and child will be the same size.

Comment: This actually works at fiddle, but on live site  `margin:0` is allready set at `body` -.-

Comment: This was just the principle. When an element has a `fixed` position, it is not bound to the same limits as its parent. What is the reason you use position `fixed` and not `absolute`?

Comment: Its a menubar. When i scrolldown 200px , it gets position fixed so it will stick on top

Comment: Did you try using `left: 0px; right: 0px` (or something similar) on the fixed element rather than the `width`? That way you can get it to fill the screen up regardless the parent

Comment: @Hans you are a lifesaver. Dunno why i never thought about it ! `left:0px` actually worked like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `position: fixed` and `top: 0` child `div` is overlapping your parent. If you need your child `div` be with `position: fixed` and you want to see the whole parent element, try to add also `position: fixed` to your parent and add some `top` value. This will show your parent elemtn under child element.

Or another solution could be is to change places for parent and child elements and use `display: inline-block` for both of them

Answer (score 0):

if you want the child element to inherit the width of the parent then it should be position absolute rather than fixed.

Comment: i allready know that it works fine with `absolute`, but i need it to have `position:fixed;`

Comment: try resetting the margin of the body to 0.      body{
 margin: 0; 
}